# Add custom template page programmatically

Tags: functions, page-template

I'm trying to add template page from a plugin,and my template page is in this plugin folder.Is this posible?Here is my code:

```
 global $user_ID;
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => 'Test Template Page',
        'post_content' => 'Some text',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_author' => $user_ID,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_category' => array(0)
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    if (!$post_id) {
        wp_die('Error creating template page');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'tp-file.php');
    }
```

tp-file.php is my custom template page.When I put that file into the my-theme folder,it works fine,but I want to do this with file from plugin folder so I don't have to force users to copy that file from plugin folder to template folder.
Is this possible?Any idea?

Comment: http://www.unfocus.com/2010/08/10/including-page-templates-from-a-wordpress-plugin/ Seems to deal with this issue.  I'm not super familiar with it, so I can't speak to whether or not it works.

Comment: Tnx @Rev.Voodoo will take a look.

Comment: @Rev.Voodoo nope,that didn't help

Comment: what is the content of tp-file.php?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The article linked is on the right track, but i'll make it more simple for you.. ;)

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'catch_plugin_template' );

function catch_plugin_template( $template ) {
    if( 'tp-file.php' == basename( $template ) )
        $template = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/yourpluginname/tp-file.php';
    return $template;
}
```

The filter basically looks to see if your special page template is set for the current page, if it is, updates the path to point at your plugins template instead.

Just be sure the path is right, else you'll be seeing include errors... :)

## Follow-up #1

Ok first problem is that WordPress validates any template set as a page template, ie. it checks to see if the file is in the theme folder, and is a valid template file, if not it skips past it and includes a more generic template, like page.php ...

However, this doesn't change the fact that the meta field still holds the value of your custom template, and also `is_page_template( 'tp-file.php' )` will correctly return true if used in place of my previous conditional statement, eg..

```
// Filter page template
add_filter('page_template', 'catch_plugin_template');

// Page template filter callback
function catch_plugin_template($template) {
    // If tp-file.php is the set template
    if( is_page_template('tp-file.php') )
        // Update path(must be path, use WP_PLUGIN_DIR and not WP_PLUGIN_URL) 
        $template = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/tp-test/tp-file.php';
    // Return
    return $template;
}
```

**NOTE:** I've switched the code to use `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` as the `WP_PLUGIN_URL` constant is not suitable for **paths**... (includes must use a path, not a URL).

One issue, and this really isn't something you can fix, is that when viewing the page from the admin area, when editting the page, the template won't be listed as the active template, and saving changes could of course change the active template. There's much we can do there, the page template dropdown is generated from a function that scans theme files, there's no hooks in place that i can see that would allows us to extend the list with plugin templates.

Personally what i'd *suggest*, as a work-around would be to save an additional meta field with every page that created using your special plugin page, then add a hook onto `save_post` or `wp_insert_post_data` and check if this meta field exists, if it does, also check the page template is set to `tp-file.php`, and if not, update it to `tp-file.php`. The additional meta field would just be a flag so to speak, to indicate which pages need to have your plugin template attached.

Here's your plugin working in it's most basic form(yes i tested)... :)

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: TP Test Plugin
  Plugin URI: 
  Description: TP Test Plugin
  Version: 1.0.0
  Author: 
  Author URI: 
*/

global $wp_version;

if( version_compare( $wp_version, "2.9", "<" ) )
    exit( 'This plugin requires WordPress 2.9 or newer. <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress">Please update!</a>' );

// Add callback to admin menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'create_tp_menu');

// Callback to add menu items
function create_tp_menu() {
    add_management_page('TP Test', 'TP Test', 'manage_options', 'tp-teste', 'wp_tp_test_fnc' );
}

function wp_tp_test_fnc() {

    //include('tp-form-file.php');

    if( !empty( $_POST['tp_name'] ) ) {
        $tp_name = $_POST['tp_name'];

        global $user_ID;
        $new_post = array(
            'post_title' => $tp_name,
            'post_content' => 'Some text',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'post_author' => $user_ID,
            'post_type' => 'page',
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

        if( !$post_id )
            wp_die('Error creating template page');
        else
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'tp-file.php' );
        /*
        $pt = get_page_templates();

        $pt['TP file test'] = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/tp-test/tp-file.php';

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($pt);
        echo "</pre>";
        */
    }   
    ?>
    <fieldset style="margin: 50px 100px;background-color: #cccccc;padding: 30px;border: 1px solid #ccc">
         <legend style="background-color: #ccccff;padding: 20px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 18px">Create Template Page</legend>
         <form name="frm_main" action="" method="POSt">
              <input class="text" type="text" name="tp_name" size="50" />
              <br />
              <input class="button" type="submit" value="Create Template Page" name="btn_submit" />
         </form>
    </fieldset>
    <?php

}


// Filter page template
add_filter('page_template', 'catch_plugin_template');

// Page template filter callback
function catch_plugin_template($template) {
    // If tp-file.php is the set template
    if( is_page_template('tp-file.php') )
        // Update path(must be path, use WP_PLUGIN_DIR and not WP_PLUGIN_URL) 
        $template = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/tp-test/tp-file.php';
    // Return
    return $template;
}
```

Hope that helps clear things up.. :)

Comment: Tnx @t31os I try it and it didn't work,than I found this http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/page_template that is deprecated,any other idea?

Comment: I also try something like this,but it didn't work : $pt = get_page_templates();
      $pt['TP testing'] = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/tp-test/tp-file.php';

Comment: It works just fine for me....  i'll need more details than "it didn't work"..

Comment: It looks like that template files are not enabled in sub folder,I found that in theme.php in get_page_templates function,any other idea?

Comment: It's not relevant, the code i supplied will work just fine providing the path is set correctly and the page requested has `_wp_page_template` set to `tp-file.php` ... I've just retested it again to be sure, and again confirmed it works(i'll need to see more of your code if you want me to help you figure out why it's not working in your setup).

Comment: Tnx for your time,my code didn't change only thing is that I added your code to my main plugin file,take a look here : http://pastebin.com/sNR9s0sP

Comment: I also double check my wp_postmeta table,it looks fine

Comment: Ok, but what happens when you load a page that has `_wp_page_template` set to `tp-file.php`? Do you see an include error, do you see a blank page, do you see something else? Help me help you... ;)

Comment: I see "Some text" like it is normal page,and if I go to backend I see that template page is set to default,and I there isn't in the list my template file

Comment: I'm heading off for bed in the next few minutes, but i'll clarify the issue tomorrow for you. As long as the meta field `_wp_page_template` remains set properly it should work, regardless of it not showing in the admin side(which is to be expected - will explain in update to answer tomorrow).

Comment: ok,tnx @t31os for helping

Comment: You're welcome... and i've just updated my answer.. ;)

Comment: Hey,this is strange,code doesn't work when form is in separate file,but if it is together,than it works.

Comment: Try setting an action on your form, eg. `action="<?php admin_url( '/?page=tp-teste' ) ?>"`, to ensure it submits to your plugin page correctly.

Comment: aaaaaaa,omg that was the problem.Tnx @t31os for your time.

Answer (score 4):

The `page_template` filter is deprecated now. (http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/page_template)

Try using `single_template` (or `archive_template` for archive templates) instead.

Based on @t31os's answer:

```
// Filter page template
add_filter('single_template', 'catch_plugin_template');

// Page template filter callback
function catch_plugin_template($template) {
    // If tp-file.php is the set template
    if( is_page_template('tp-file.php') )
        // Update path(must be path, use WP_PLUGIN_DIR and not WP_PLUGIN_URL) 
        $template = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/tp-test/tp-file.php';
    // Return
    return $template;
}
```

Comment: if `single_template` filter did not work, you can use this filter;
`add_filter('template_include', 'catch_plugin_template');`

taken from here; https://www.pradipdebnath.com/2019/08/17/how-to-add-page-template-from-plugin-in-wordpress/

Comment: Not shure is it deprecated, just changed since 4.7. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/.The argument is empty if theme(s) dont provide the template, not if the page has selected (stored it) in the database from the select dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

> One issue, and this really isn't something you can fix, is that when
> viewing the page from the admin area, when editting the page, the
> template won't be listed as the active template, and saving changes
> could of course change the active template. There's much we can do
> there, the page template dropdown is generated from a function that
> scans theme files, there's no hooks in place that i can see that would
> allows us to extend the list with plugin templates.

Actually I found a hook in another thread that does exactly that:

[WordPress: Can you programmatically create page templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662858/wordpress-can-you-programmatically-create-page-templates)

I am pasting the code here for convenience:

```
CONST CUSTOM_PAGE_TEMPLATES = array(
  array('slug' => 'home', 'label' => 'Home'),
  array('slug' => 'content-page', 'label' => 'Content Page'),
  array('slug' => 'ordering', 'label' => 'Ordering'),
  array('slug' => 'reviews', 'label' => 'Reviews')
); 

/**
 * Add file-less page templates to the page template dropdown 
 */
add_filter('theme_page_templates', function($page_templates, $wp_theme, $post) {
  foreach(CUSTOM_PAGE_TEMPLATES as $template) {
    // Append if it doesn't already exists
    if (!isset($page_templates[$template['slug']])) {
      $page_templates[$template['slug']] = $template['label'];
    }
  }
  return $page_templates;
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 3);
```

Hope that helps someone.