# Auto-Create Pages from Template Directory

Tags: pages, templates, automation

Is there a way to have WordPress automatically create static pages from all of the template files in a given directory?

So rather than manually creating custom page templates in the WP dashboard, I'd like to write a script that looks at every file in a directory and creates a new custom page template for each one based on the template name given in the `/* Template Name: Foo */` declaration.

I'm familiar with the solution offered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/13451/13431), but it still seems to require manually entering the pages one at a time.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you want. You want WordPress to recognize the files as if they were [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) files?

Comment: Yes exactly - I edited my question to hopefully make it more clear what I'm looking for.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you need them to be recognized as such?

Comment: Do you still not understand what I'm asking or are you questioning the validity of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I understand what you are asking but I have not found a way to do it.