# Using a Page Template Not in Theme

Tags: plugin-development, pages, page-template

My plugin creates (on demand via a 'create template' button) a page template that is stored in `uploads/plugin-name` folder (so it will survive a plugin update).

The plugin also creates (again on demand) a post that needs to use that template. It does this with the `wp_create_post` function:

```
    $template_file = "/the/absolute/path/to/wp-content/uploads/plugin-name/custom-template.php";
    $new_page        = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_title' => 'The Custom Page',
        'post_content' => $some_content,  // text for the content, previously defined
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_slug' => 'the-custom-page',
        'page_template' => $template_file,
    );
    $the_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
```

The `_wp_page_template` meta value is properly stored in the postmeta table for that post ID, that record has the value of the absolute path to the custom template.

My issue is with how to ensure that the custom page uses the custom template. The docs are not clear whether the page can use a template file (the posts' _wp_page_template meta value) with an **absolute** path, rather than a path **relative** to the current theme.

The intent is to have a theme-independent template that can be used for the custom page. I've been able to properly store the template meta value for the post, but can't get the custom page to use it - even though that custom template is shown in the 'template' dropdown for that page.

Comment: It's not enough to just set value for the post meta, WP looks for the templates in the theme directory. You also need to hook the template include (there's a few different spots you can do this) to set the template path when it matches your custom saved value. I posted an updated and general (multiple post types) approach recently [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/410994/31073) for using page templates from a plugin (maybe you can pluck something useful from there).

Comment: Doesn't template_include use the meta value? So is the meta value an absolute path or a path relative to the current theme? How can you get the post to use an absolute value for the template location?

Comment: WP reads the meta and looks to find a matching template in the theme's directory, it's necessary to run your own filter otherwise this check returns false and the internal logic continues it way down to the next file in the template hierarchy. Not sure i completely follow regarding the path, you can set this to absolutely anywhere you want when you build/set it in your `page_template` or equivalent filter.